# Display the latest row only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, max

Goal:
If you retrieve any duplicate data that is data in the column secondid, then you to retrieve one row only from the latest date. For instance in the data below I have two different datetime, I would like to retrieve the data '2016-05-02 07:34:14.377' from value 6 in column secondid.

Problem:
I code seems not to be working and what am I missing.

Info:
There are many data in and you cannot hard code the value in in the code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testing2](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [secondid] [int] NULL,
    [value] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [category] [int] NULL,
    [test_id] [int] NULL,
    [id_type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Testing2Datetime] [datetime] not NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_testing2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing2]
VALUES (3, 3, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,1, '2016-05-01 07:34:14.377');

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing2]
VALUES (4, 4, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,1, '2016-05-01 07:34:14.377');

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing2]
VALUES (5, 5, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,0, '2016-05-01 07:34:14.377');

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing2]
VALUES (6, 6, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,2, '2016-05-01 07:34:14.377');

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing2]
VALUES (7, 6, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,2, '2016-05-02 07:34:14.377');



select
    bb.secondid,
    max(bb.Testing2Datetime)
from [dbo].[testing2] bb
group by
    bb.secondid,
        bb.Testing2Datetime
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value of `Testing2Datetime` per `Testing2Datetime` is the `Testing2Datetime` itself. You should remove it from the `group by` clause and retrieve the maximum value per **`secondid`** only:

```
select
    bb.secondid,
    max(bb.Testing2Datetime)
from [dbo].[testing2] bb
group by
    bb.secondid -- Here!
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `bb.Testing2Datetime` column from `Group by`

```
select
    bb.secondid,
    max(bb.Testing2Datetime) as [Max_Testing2Datetime]
from [dbo].[testing2] bb
group by
    bb.secondid
```

or even this(`Row_Number` window function)

```
select * 
from 
(
select
    bb.secondid,
    bb.Testing2Datetime,
    Row_number()over(partition by bb.secondid order by bb.Testing2Datetime desc) as RN
from [dbo].[testing2] bb
) A
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!